# nested for loop through two vectors

Tags: rust

I want something like this in Rust but I don't understand the compile errors:

```
fn main() {
    let apple: String = String::from("apple");
    let accle: String = String::from("accle");

    let apple_vec: Vec<char> = apple.chars().collect();
    let accle_vec: Vec<char> = accle.chars().collect();
    
    let counter = 0;
    for j in accle_vec {
        for i in apple_vec {
          // if i == j{ 
            counter++;
          // }
        }
    }
    println!("counter is {}", counter);
}
```

I want to compare the characters of two arrays, one by one, and count every time there is a mismatch.

Comment: What errors you cannot understand? It is much better to post those errors in the question.

Comment: Your code has three main problems and it is rather straightforward to fix according to the compiler's output :Change `counter++` to `counter+=1`; Change `let counter` to `let mut counter` to make it mutable; Borrow the two `Vec` with `&` in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several things going on here, so let's break this down.

First error we hit is:

```
error: expected expression, found `+`
  --> src/main.rs:12:21
   |
12 |             counter++;
   |                     ^ expected expression

error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

This means that this is invalid syntax. That is because rust does not have `++`, instead we can use `counter += 1` or `counter = counter + 1`. I'll use the first.

Making this change, we get a few errors, but concentrating on the `counter`, we see:

```
error[E0384]: cannot assign twice to immutable variable `counter`
  --> src/main.rs:12:13
   |
8  |     let counter = 0;
   |         -------
   |         |
   |         first assignment to `counter`
   |         help: consider making this binding mutable: `mut counter`
...
12 |             counter += 1;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot assign twice to immutable variable

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0382, E0384.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
```

The advice we get is sound - the counter is declared as immutable and we are trying to mutate it. We should declare it as mutable. So `let mut counter = 0`

Lastly, we get the following error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `apple_vec`
   --> src/main.rs:10:18
    |
5   |     let apple_vec: Vec<char> = apple.chars().collect();
    |         --------- move occurs because `apple_vec` has type `Vec<char>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
10  |         for i in apple_vec {
    |                  ^^^^^^^^^
    |                  |
    |                  `apple_vec` moved due to this implicit call to `.into_iter()`, in previous iteration of loop
    |                  help: consider borrowing to avoid moving into the for loop: `&apple_vec`
    |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `apple_vec`
```

This is because iterating over the inner vector in this way would drain it on the first pass and on the second pass of the outer loop inner iteration would be impossible. In order to prevent this, you can borrow the vec for the iteration instead like `for i in &apple_vec`

Putting this all together would yield the following code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let apple: String = String::from("apple");
    let accle: String = String::from("accle");

    let apple_vec: Vec<char> = apple.chars().collect();
    let accle_vec: Vec<char> = accle.chars().collect();
    
    let mut counter = 0;
    for j in &accle_vec {
        for i in &apple_vec {
           if i == j {
                counter += 1;
           }
        }
    }
    println!("counter is {}", counter);
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for all of the changes that are not equal. if i.ne(j) (or i != j), counter returns as 22 which doesn't make sense? -- nevermind I realized I'm using nested for loops, that's exactly what 22 means, sorry nevermind

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would write the code, in a more functional manner:

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let apple: String = String::from("appleb");
    let accle: String = String::from("acclea");
    
    // this goes through both strings at the same time
    // eg. a==a p!=c p!=c
    // I think maybe this was your goal
    // It'll find matches where the same character is in the same position in
    // both strings
    
    // Iterate through the characters of the first string
    let count1 = apple.chars()
        // zip in the char from the second string
        .zip(accle.chars())
        // Now you have the char from the first and the second strings
        // .. and you're still iterating.
        // Filter so that you only keep entries where both chars are the same
        .filter(|(a, b)| a == b)
        // Count the output
        .count();
        
    // This is like having nested loops, where it'll compare
    // the first 'a' to every letter in the second word
    // eg. 'a' == 'a', 'a' != 'c'
    // Using the above values, it returns one extra because there are two
    // matches for 'a' in "acclea"
    // This is what your original code was doing I think
    
    // iterate through the chars of the first string
    let count2 = apple.chars()
        // For every char from the first string, iterate through
        // *all* the chars of the second string
        .flat_map(|a| accle.chars()
            // Instead of just returning the char from the second string
            // Return a tuple containing the char from the first string and
            // the second
            .map(move |b| (a, b)))
        // Only accept instances where both chars are the same
        .filter(|(a, b)| a == b)
        // Count them
        .count();
        
    // To just see if a char from "apple" is in "accle" (anyhere)
    // I would just write
    let count3 = apple.chars()
        // Only accept a char from "apple" if it can also be found in
        // "accle"
        .filter(|a| accle.chars().any(|b| *a == b))
        .count();
        
    // If speed was important and words were long, you could get all the chars
    // from "accle" and put them in a HashSet
    let set: HashSet<char> = accle.chars().collect();
    let count4 = apple.chars()
        .filter(|a| set.contains(a))
        .count();

    println!("Count1 is {}", count1);
    println!("Count2 is {}", count2);
    println!("Count3 is {}", count3);
    println!("Count4 is {}", count4);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a0179da11588eba531ddca8454b9883f)

Comment: A super quick question. How do I get the ith position in an vector, like array1[ith] and array2[jth] in rust

Comment: @spaceghost .nth() - https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.nth